# Numpy recursive compare against all data in row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a booleen numpy array as follows:

```
bool_arr = array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
                  [False, False,  True,  True],
                  [False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I want to compare, along the rows, returning `True` only for the first instance of `True`, otherwise return `False`.  So the correct answer to the comparison I'd like to `bool_arr` would be:

```
ans = array([[ True,  False,  False,  False],
             [False, False,  True,  False],
             [False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I can't figure out the "Numpy" way to do this without loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the cumulative-sum along axis=1, twice, and detect the first `True` value as the one having the value 1:

```
bool_arr.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1) == 1
=>
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Notes:

- applying arithmetic, such as sum, to bool values, treats them as integers 0 and 1
- applying `cumsum` only once would work on the example in the qeustion, but not in cases where you have `False` immediately after the first `True`. The second `cumsum` takes care of that.

Comment: Now the real question -- Does this perform better than a naive for-loop implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along axis=1 to find the index of the first `True` value in each row, and then construct a new array and assign `True` in those indices:

```
res = zeros_like(bool_arr)
res[arange(res.shape[0]),argmax(bool_arr, axis=1)] = True
```

This relies on the fact `argmax` returns the index of the *first* of the maximal values.

---

EDIT:
@unutbu pointed out this doesn't work for rows which contain no `True` values. To make this work, we can mask the indices:

```
m = bool_arr.any(axis=1)
res = zeros_like(bool_arr)
res[ arange(res.shape[0])[m] , argmax(bool_arr, axis=1)[m] ] = True
```

Comment: `np.argmax(np.array([False]*4))` equals 0. So, unfortunately, `res[arange(res.shape[0]),argmax(bool_arr, axis=1)] = True` would place a True at the 0th index, even though the row is entirely filled with Falses.